# Cannot select a binded item from another controller in combobox or choicebox

Tags: java, binding, combobox, javafx

I have three controllers say ParentController, ChildController1, and ChildController2. The ParentController loads all children controllers at the same time. I have a list1 from ChildController1 and I want to bind it to the list2 of ChildController2. Here's a sample code:

**ParentController.java**

```
public class ParentController{
    ChildController1 controller1;
    ChildController2 controller2;

    loadControllers();
}


public void loadControllers(){
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new   FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view1.fxml"));
    Parent root1 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    controller1 = fxmlLoader.getController();

    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new   FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view1.fxml"));
    Parent root2 = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load();
    controller2 = fxmlLoader.getController();

    Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(controller1.list1, controller2.list2);
}
```

**ChildController1.java**

```
public class ChildController1{

    @FXML
    Button addItem;

    @FXML
    TextField textField;

    ObservableList list1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList("apple", "grapes");

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
        addItem.setOnAction(e->{
            list1.add(textField.getText());
        });
    }

}
```

**ChildController2.java**

```
public class ChildController2{
    @FXML
    ComboBox combobox;
    ObservableList list2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
        combobox.setItems(list2);
    }
}
```

When running the application, the first two items ("apple" and "grapes") can be selected in the combobox of controller2. But when I add a new string in list1 say "orange", "orange" was visible in the combobox item list but it is impossible to select it.

Any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make this into a complete example; it basically works fine for me. The code you have seems fine - the error must be elsewhere.

Comment: you're right.. i thought the error was in my controllers or in the binding.. it was actually in the object i'm trying to add to the list. I've posted the more detailed sample.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

You try to load two time the same fxml documents. There are two problems, first you have to set the location on a new loader and after that call load() on it. Second, if you set the controller in your fxml document by tag "fx:controller", then you cannot load the the fxml two times. This is because the context already exists for fxml and controller pair.

If you change your code to do the loading correctly, then you will get an exception:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Root value already specified.
```

### Assumption/Question

Do you try to create a new Window? If you try, this attempt would be a fail. New Windows (Stages) need a Scene and a Stage, but this is a different question.

### Solution

Create two distinct fxml - controller pairs. Then make a **typed** observable list, and after that you be able to bibind the two lists.

```
  public void loadControllers() throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader child1Loader = new FXMLLoader();
    child1Loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Child1.fxml"));
    Parent root1 = child1Loader.load();
    controller1 = child1Loader.getController();

    FXMLLoader child2Loader = new FXMLLoader();
    child2Loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("Child2.fxml"));
    Parent root2 = (Parent) child1Loader.load();
    controller2 = child2Loader.getController();

    Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(controller1.getObservableList(), controller2.getObservableList());
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying to make one window only where I can change the scene depending on the scene i set. Then I want to pass all the items from the other controller to the other controller.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem. It was actually in the list of items I put on the observablelist **list1**. Here's the detailed sample:

```
@FXML
ComboBox<Fruit> fruits;

ObservableList<Ingredient> list1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){

    Fruit apple = new Fruit("apple");
    Fruit mango = new Fruit("mango");

    fruits.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(apple, mango));

    addButton.setOnAction(e->{
        Ingredient i = new Ingredient(fruits.getValue(), 5);
        list1.add(i);
    });
}
```

**Ingredient.java**

```
class Ingredient{
    @Expose
    int id;
    @Expose
    Fruit fruit;
    @Expose
    double quantity;

    public Ingredient(Fruit fruit, double quantity){
        this.fruit = fruit;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if (!(object instanceof Ingredient)) {
            return false;
        }

        Ingredient other = (Ingredient) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

After removing the two generated overrides hashcode() and equals(), everything works fine now.